# wordpress users redirect to previus page when login

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to create function for redirect wordpress users to previous page after login
my function is not work correctly?
what is the problem?

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = admin_url();
        } else {
            $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You are just redirecting to the current page `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  redirect user to login page again! and $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] redirect user to home page!